# java android open street map slider to zoom map

Tags: java, android

I want to have a slider to zoom map , no I have this zoom controls :

```
<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />
```

[image]

But I want to have a slider to zoomno this bottons

Comment: What did you try to do that? Where are the problems? Any kind of effort?

Comment: @GAlexMES I don't have idea how I can do this

Comment: @GAlexMES and I try use a seekBar

Comment: which lib are you using? (osmdroid? Mapsforge?) Is you question about layout (put a seekbar overlay over that map) or how to implement map zoomTo?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using osmdroid-lib you have to implement it yourself.

Create a FrameLayout that contains the map and a seekbar on top of the map like this.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- the gui -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cright_osm"
            android:text="@string/osm_cright_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/zoomBar"
            android:layout_above="@id/cright_osm"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/zoomBar"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[Here](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/locationmap/LocationMapFragment.java) is a code fragment that implements a zoombar